# How to remember parameter values used on last build in Jenkins/Hudson

Tags: groovy, jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins

I need to remember the last parameter values when I begin a new build with parameters.

I have two string parameters:

```
${BRANCH}
${ServerSpecified}
```

On the first build execution I need those values in blank, but for the second execution, I need the values of the first execution, in the third execution the values of the second execution, and so on...

Do I need to install a plugin? I have tried using dynamic param with groovy, but I can't extract the last value. Does anybody know how to do this or have any other idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it looks like you are trying to invent something like [Version Number Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Version+Number+Plugin):

> This plugin creates a new version number and stores it in the
>   environment variable whose name you specify in the configuration.

So you can as many variables as you want.

Comment: Thank you man, but I can resolved the problem with other way.. with this line `def test = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItem("6.6 Dev Brafton Deploy").lastBuild.getBuildVariables().get("BRANCH");` in the dynamic param

Comment: Hi @DavidDominguez, I'm new in Jenkins. Please tell me where to write this line?

Comment: @SanjayRaz You must first to install dynamic param plugin... after put this code on the configuration of the param.. So I did that 6 years ago.. Maybe the dynamic param  has been changed

Answer (score 4):

In order to retrieve parameters from previous executions, you can follow this approach in your pipeline:

```
def defaultValueForMyParameter = "My_Default_Value"

node('master') {
    parameterValue = params.MY_PARAMETER ?: defaultValueForMyParameter
}

pipeline {

    parameters {
        string(name: 'MY_PARAMETER', defaultValue: parameterValue, description: "whatever")
    }

    ...
}
```

This code keeps track on the last value used for the parameter allowing to change it before or during the run. If the parameter does not exist in the job, it will be created and the default value will be assigned to it.

Comment: I personally am not a fan of retaining parameters across builds because there is the replay button for that, however I was asked to do just that today. I tried a lot of ways to do that and I must say I don't find this solution sexy but this is the only one that works in every scenario I tried so far. Thanks Sergio

Answer (score 3):

There is a [Rebuild plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Rebuild+Plugin) that would allow you to re-build any job of interest. It also allows you to modify one or more of the original build parameters

Answer (score 2):

No one mentions the [Persistent Parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Persistent+Parameter+Plugin), which is the one I use.

Supports string parameters, choice, and more.

Answer (score 0):

Every few months/years I have to do the same thing, and I scratch my head for "how did I solve it last time?". It's the same solution like @sergio-prats wrote, but with a twist:

```js
pipeline {
    agent { label any }

    parameters {
        string(name: 'TARGET_SYS',
                defaultValue: params.TARGET_SYS ? params.TARGET_SYS : 'system1',
                description: 'Target system')
    }
...
}
```

The same can be done for choice parameters, e.g.:

```js
import groovy.transform.Field

@Field
List<String> TARGET_SYS_VALUES = ['ci', 'dev', 'test', 'staging']

pipeline {
    agent { label any }

    parameters {
        choice(name: 'TARGET_SYS',
                choices: (params.TARGET_SYS ? [params.TARGET_SYS] : []) +
                             (TARGET_SYS_VALUES - 
                                 (params.TARGET_SYS ? [params.TARGET_SYS] : [])),
                description: 'Some fictive target systems')
    }
...
}
```

How does this work? In Jenkins pipelines `params` contains the job/build parameter values for *current* build. That HashMap is initialized *before* the `parameters` *definition block* is evaluated. That re-evaluation happens on *each build*. So:

- `string` evaluates the `defaultValue` in each build N, and offers that value in *next* build N+1.
- `choice` doesn't have a `defaultValue` option. Instead the first value of the `choices` option is offered as default value. This option is also evaluated during each build, and offered in the *next* build.