# Jenkins Plugin config.jelly get previous input values in config

Tags: java, jenkins

I'm creating a Jenkins plugin and I'm trying to get the form to be automatically filled with previous config values.

This is similar to a field I currently have:

```
<strong class="required-field">Test</strong>
<f:entry field="test">
    <f:textbox placeholder="test input"/>
</f:entry>
```

I'm trying to do something similar to this but inside a config.jelly file: [How to remember parameter values used on last build in Jenkins/Hudson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513130/how-to-remember-parameter-values-used-on-last-build-in-jenkins-hudson)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like this was documented anywhere but the fields need to have getters for the form to be populated with previous results.

Examples:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/8293c49a5a053bdad6b2212728ba72e127f88a82/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/git/GitStep.java#L65

https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/jenkins/plugins/git/GitStep/config.jelly